# Are answers which misunderstood the question low quality?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, low-quality-posts

Let's say an OP asks:

> ***Why*** does X produces this result?

An answer is

> ***To make it work***, change, etc...

The answer obviously misunderstood the question. The goal is not to correct the original behavior, but to understand it. But it is still an attempt to address the OP's issue.

Is an answer which misunderstood the question like this low-quality and need to be flagged for review? In my opinion, such answers need to be downvoted with a comment, not flagged for deletion.

Some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5931369
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5931240

Comment: Things like this are nearly always evaluated on a case-by-case basis. Your example specifically can be handled by voting, allowing a direct A to the Q to raise up. The answer (as per your example) could remain but not as highly voted as it might be helpful to others who actually want the fix. Again, case-by-case, as perhaps there is no fix at all, and the user simply asking about how something works - why X makes Y value do Z.

Comment: I'd agree. Flag posts that are harmful, down vote ones that are wrong.

Comment: You need to distinguish between `low quality` and `wrong`, though we do have cases when both attributes apply.  If it's clear and unambiguous what the answer says it's **not** `low quality`.

Comment: I don't think those are good examples.  The first one *is* very low quality in and of itself, regardless of the question; to apply Andrew's criteria, it is incomprehensible.  The second one is a sound answer to the question (essentially equivalent to the accepted answer) so the only problem is that it is not expressed well.  I would neither downvote nor vote to close.

Comment: The first example is definitely low quality, possibly in addition to being wrong.  How can you tell?  "Because!"

Comment: It needs to be pointed out that by common convention, "why is this broken" is sometimes [pragmatically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) equivalent to "how do I fix it?"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"Low Quality" is a very over-used flag, in my opinion. It basically should be for things that are simply incomprehensible and can't possibly be fixed. It is basically, "this thing just sucks so much, it should be wiped out. Right now. Please. Thank you."

*Except* that it should not be for spam, offensive, or "Not an Answer"; there are other flags for those things.

Also, the type of thing you note would not be appropriate for "Not an Answer", either. The key there being from the NAA text: "...an *attempt* to answer the question." That sort of thing is an *attempt*; bad, wrong, misguided though it *may* be.

---

All of which is to say; I believe you are correct. Down vote, comment (or ignore), but not flag.

Comment: _"Low Quality" is a very over-used flag_ - Yes, yes it is.  And it is consistently used wrong.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to see some examples of properly flagged VLQ posts.

Comment: Not to mention low quality and very low quality are different flags.

Comment: I agree with this answer. However, the close reasons are not entirely clear as to which to use where. I know this point has been bashed to death, but it still stands that newer users, or those who do not frequent Metas, cannot logically or easily ascertain which close method to use. "Low quality" is very contextual in itself, both your answer and this question use the words "In my opinion...". The problem is amplified given that there are numerous potential scenarios where suitability of the different close methods can be (and has been) open to interpretation.

Comment: @James I don't disagree. That's actually why I stated it as my opinion, in fact. ;)

Comment: @chris Did you mean answers, rather than suggested edits? I  don't know about editing these answers; they wouldn't be good enough to fix. It'd be better to post your own answer.

Comment: Just for clarification: Such low quality answers should be edited (typos, noise, etc.) and down-voted, but not deleted?

Comment: That's what I figured, @Chris. My comment was based on that assumption :)