# Does answering the wrong question make an answer not an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

Spurred by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality) asking about flagging answers that answered the wrong question as very low quality.  The relevant parts of the question are

> Let's say an OP asks:
>
> ```
> Why does X produces this result?
> ```
>
> An answer is
>
> ```
> To make it work, change, etc...
> ```
>
> The answer obviously misunderstood the question. The goal is not to
>   correct the original behavior, but to understand it. But it is still
>   an attempt to address the OP's issue.

An answerer posted this as part of their answer:

> Also, the type of thing you note would not be appropriate for "Not
>   an Answer", either. The key there being from the NAA text: "...an
>   attempt to answer the question." That sort of thing is an attempt;
>   bad, wrong, misguided though it may be.

Is an answer that answers the wrong question really an attempt to answer the question? Now clearly it is an attempt to answer **a** question but not **the** question.  I know that may be nit-picking, but the answer feels like noise to me.  If someone needs help getting their foo to bar they are probably more interested in the how than the why.  If the how question exists, that answer probably belongs there.  If it doesn't, then that someone will hopefully ask it.  At that point we probably don't need the answer that is in search of the question.

So my ultimate question is: is that answer really an answer? And should it get flagged as not an answer?

Comment: It is an answer, and should not be flagged. Downvote it if you find it to be not useful in answering the question or incorrect. On the other hand, if it were an attempt to comment or a request for additional information, it would be a good candidate for the NAA flag. this is probably a dupe

Comment: @KevinB I saw that post when I was looking for an answer to this.  That question seems to deal more with things that are clearly not answers at all (asking for clarification, saying thanks, etc.)  I'm trying to focus on finding out if an answer really qualifies as an answer (and not noise) if it is not answering the question that was asked.

Comment: That's a very subjective issue though, and can be affected by language barriers. For example, lets look at the question you pointed out. That can be interpreted both ways; literally asking to describe a behavior, or, they're actually trying to make the behavior not happen. And, if they were looking for the literal answer, there's a pretty good chance the next thing they'll want is the latter.

Comment: In the end, it's still an attempt to answer the question, even if the interpretation of the question was wrong. Therefore, it is an answer, and the NAA flag is not appropriate. The answer can be dealt with by the community without moderator attention.

Comment: @KevinB I really would hope such a non-answer gets downvoted to oblivion, though that quite often does not happen. Very aggravating when the opposite happens.