# How to mark an answer as "It doesn't answer the question that was asked?"

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

Is there any other way apart from Vote Down to mark an Answer as not an answer to the specific question?

There could be cases where the person who posted the answer has misunderstood the question or didn't pay close attention to details provided in the question, before posting his answer. In such cases, how do we deal with the answers posted.

The reason for asking this is, I normally skip Answered questions (irrespective of whether its accepted or not), unless the title is intriguing or makes me feel I would learn something out of that discussion. If not all, many a people (or say many of potential answerer for the question) might be browsing with same mindset. The bogus answer thus effectively will bring down the attention the question otherwise would have received.

***Ref:*** This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762905/positioning-divs-using-css-float-div-below-another-div) from me and the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27762915/1261124) it received is what prompted me to post this question here!

**Note:** I am aware of Flagging it as [it is not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81389/when-should-you-decide-whether-to-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/81392#81392) but usage of the flag doesn't seem appropriate in the case I have mentioned above.

**Edit:** I do agree the [linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality) (with 1 answer) probably is similar to this question. The accepted answer over there suggests us to Down Vote and Comment on a non-answer (but not Flag them). This certainly doesn't address the problem of a question receiving less attention (as it would appear "answered" on the main feed), which is the primary concern raised here.

***Linked to:*** [Don't show answered color if the question qualifies as unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242385/dont-show-answered-color-if-the-question-qualifies-as-unanswered)

Comment: Would it be an option to have a way to view average question votes (or number of answers with >0 votes) in the feed?

Comment: Adding "number of answers with >0 votes"  to feed seems like a good suggestion!

Comment: Why not add a comment to the non-answer.  Then the poster has the chance to improve or delete it.

Comment: @Andrew Swann: He did.

Comment: Personally, I think that higher-rep users should have the power to delete answers that they do not like on their own questions.

Comment: @Joehot200 They already do. And not only on their own question. With the [trusted user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege (20K) you can vote to delete answers with score of -1 or lower (among other things).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242385/dont-show-answered-color-if-the-question-qualifies-as-unanswered

Comment: Changed your title, hopefully to convey more accurately what you are actually asking.  "Not an Answer" means something else.

Comment: There's no issue, really, you just got a bad answer. It happens, a lot. Down vote it. As to the psychological effect it will have on other potential answerers, I don't think there's any hard data to suggest that most questions only get one answer whether it is accepted or not. Indeed, one can find tens of thousands of instances where a question received multiple answers. Going further: if a user is the type of rep-chasing skimmer that won't give a question with an answer a look, then we're all probably better off that they moved along instead of posting some minimal "get the rep" answer.

Comment: See also [this request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag), which discusses changing the flag dialog to make this issue clearer.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Downvote, and comment if the problem has not yet been pointed out.

Flagging is **entirely inappropriate**.  You could be wrong; there might actually be a connection that you have not understood.  Determining whether the answer applies to the question is a job for an expert, not a moderator.

(I don't believe you are wrong in this particular case, but my point that only subject matter experts can determine that still stands)

It's not really even different for the question author... we have plenty of incompetent people asking questions, and even more who don't like the correct answers they are given.  Remember that the point of answers isn't to help you personally, it's to be correct and informative.  As the question asker you control the green checkmark; you don't get to censor information.

If you want to propose a feature that questions with only downvoted answers show in the question list as still unanswered, I'd agree with that.  The vote count treats the question asker and other experts in the topic equally, which IMO is the right thing to do.

And of course, if you haven't gotten a satisfactory answer within two days, perhaps because there's a highly upvoted answer to the question you asked, but the question you meant to ask remains open... there is always the option of a bounty.

Comment: Then, under what circumstances would the flag option whose description starts _"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question"_ be appropriate to use?

Comment: @DavidWallace:You're taking that quote that out of context.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer

Comment: Not intentionally!  Thanks for that other link though; it clears it up.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, even if an answer is incorrect it still *attempts* to answer the question, so this flag option is inappropriate. Just downvote + comment and some moderator will probably see it and remove it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I believe, last two paragraphs from your answer would definitely solve the issue. I see a similar [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281710/how-to-mark-an-answer-as-it-doesnt-answer-the-question-that-was-asked) in meta SE. Should I just get it linked with this question or start a new question in meta SO?

Comment: Your link just points back here.  In any case, you should definitely link between this discussion and the feature request.  Whether you add an additional site-local feature request is up to you.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oops, I meant this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242385/dont-show-answered-color-if-the-question-qualifies-as-unanswered

Comment: This seems to assume that the general populous is better placed to decide whether the answer answers their question, than the original asker is.... others may think the answer is of poor quality (ie downvote) but if the asker feels it answered their question, that acceptance is still valid.

Comment: @Jon: Users who meet the rep requirement for voting and are sufficiently interested in the topic to come across the answer and vote are better able to judge the answer than many brand new users coming asking questions.  It's true that some questions are asked by experts, but these are very much the minority and also those experts heavily influence the voting with the informative comments they leave.  There's no problem.

Comment: Indeed, and they're welcome to upvote and downvote - but they are still not better placed to accept the answer, so downvotes shouldn't prevent an answer being accepted

Comment: @JonStory: Downvotes don't prevent the green checkmark from being given, nor did I suggest that they should.  I think you missed the point of this whole question, which is looking for a way for the asker to get rid of answers he thinks are unhelpful, so the question appears on the front page as "0 answers".  A better way than "getting rid of the answer" is just to have it not counted, so people looking for unanswered questions will still be drawn to this question.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I confused "unanswered" and "unaccepted" in your answer - long day!

Comment: @BenVoigt that's why "unanswered" doesn't count answers with no votes. (unlike unanswered > no answers).