# Here we go again, declined link-only flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I got a declined Not An Answer (NAA) flag on this answer: [AngularJS : Clear $watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957614/angular-js-clear-watch/32526185#32526185)

> See if the Demo here helps, $watch service is used To set a handler that will be invoked when the value reffered to by the expression
>   http://www.tutorialspark.com/AngularJS/AngularJS_Updating_Scopes.php

The original question is this:

> I have a watch function at my Angular Js application.
>
> ```
> $scope.$watch('quartzCrystal', function () {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> However after some condition(in my example changing the page at my single page application) I want to stop that watch (as like clearing timeout)
>
> How can I do that?

Obviously, the person asking the question knows what the `$watch` service does. It does not make any effort to answer the question that is asked. It's the equivalent of "How do I dunk a basketball?" Answer: "A basketball is a ball used in the sport of basketball."

[This had a unanimous four Recommend Deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9476315) in the Low Quality Posts Queue when a moderator declined the flag.

This is NAA, and I will be voting to delete it tomorrow when I get my votes back if it's not already gone via the meta effect.

Comment: Related: [How to mark an answer as “It doesn't answer the question that was asked?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281710/how-to-mark-an-answer-as-it-doesnt-answer-the-question-that-was-asked?lq=1)  Yeah it sucks a bit, but at least the VLQ queue will probably do its job.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It doesn't answer any question **at all**

Comment: I think its an unfortunate looks by itself _kinda, enough_ like an answer.  I mean like in your analogy "A basketball is a ball used in the sport of basketball." looks enough like a (really unhelpful) answer.  Remember that by default, mods only see the answer for NAA flags.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I did flag them for moderation. And got declined.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Unfortunately, the other four answers by this user, while crap, are not flaggable.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: "unhelpful answer" is a great way of putting it. I've seen so many of those in my daily use of the site that if I had deleted those as NAA, I would have deleted quite a number of those answers outside the mod queue - and I don't often come across true blue NAAs outside of the queue.

Comment: @BoltClock You would have declined this flag as well, then?

Comment: I probably would have. I could make a case for the answer referring to "the Demo here" and thus depending heavily on the link to be useful, but it's hard to tell at a glance without context if the additional sentence does anything to alleviate that dependency. And that's the problem with borderline cases.

Comment: @BoltClock Bleh. I've really got to be less lazy about writing out the custom flag then. I try to avoid custom flagging to allow the LQPQ to handle it without bothering a moderator :-/

Answer (score 22):

I'm the mod that declined that flag.

Now while its better content should be included, the first sentence is:

> See if the Demo here helps, **$watch service is used To set a handler that will be invoked when the value reffered to by the expression**

(emphasis mine - heck for I know, without looking at the Q. that might well be an answer, and looks like one (albeit a poor one)).

Seems to be reasonable enough to the title of the question. The link also ends in *AngularJS_Updating_Scopes.php* - they look like potentially useful search terms if nothing else.

Since this is a borderline case, and you're a trusted user (20k+), you're able to downvote and cast a delete vote. That would have been the better action in this case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this meta post. I still disagree, but I appreciate the response.

Comment: The reason why I don't like downvoting and delete voting is that the 10k tools are not a reliable way to get eyeballs on an answer. Flagging the post puts it in the Low Quality Posts Queue to get the eyeballs needed for deletion.

Comment: Hm. Failed to find any post (among 5 answers he posted) where that user *doesn't* promote his site.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well you won't be finding any posts where he *does* promote his site now either ;)

Comment: @BoltClock vacuuous satisfaction is the most satisfying