# Are answers that completely ignore the explicit constraints of the question Very Low Quality?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

This question is a follow-up to: [Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)

Also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Also: [Are answers which misunderstood the question low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality)

I recently encountered a question where the OP was explicitly asking about how to add training data without retraining their ML model from scratch. The answer, however, explained how they could retrain it from scratch (which is exactly what the OP said that they were trying to avoid).

At risk of the Meta effect, here's the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63860841/4032703) (image below in case this gets deleted):

> [image]

What's the proper way to handle this? Downvote it and comment (as someone else already did), vote to delete (for people who have enough rep to do so), or flag as NAA? On the one hand, it was at least an *attempt* to answer the question, but on the other hand, it clearly *doesn't* answer the question at all - the OP was extremely clear about the constraints of the question and the answer completely ignores them. Following the example in [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), it seems like the answer is providing an orange instead of an apple.

That being said, how should we handle these? Is it OK to flag as NAA based on it being an orange instead of an apple?

Comment: Considering we don't flag incorrect answers, these should probably not be flagged either. Downvote and move on

Comment: no flag here, downvote and move on. It's an answer but not a *not useful* one. It doesn't need any moderator intervention

Comment: You treat it like any answer attempt, down- or upvote, but don't flag for a mod. The accepted answer on your other answer is rather clear on that (that answer counts for all mod flags, not just VLQ).

Comment: While the second part of the answer completely ignores the constraints, the first part of the answer "You can either resize the new input images" seems perfectly valid.

Comment: Seems like the answer is saying the only way to avoid retraining from scratch is to resize the new images. It might not be an answer the OP likes, since it's not a programmatic way around their issue, but it does address the question as asked.

Comment: That's not an orange. That's a "pink lady" when author asked for "granny smith". Last time I saw one one those it had a score of over 900.

Comment: Sometimes ignoring a restriction in an answer is worth it. When answers jump through hoops to fulfill some arcane restriction you have to worry that some future asker will stumble across the question, copy the insane code, and join the Cargo Cult. Having an answer that shows a practical solution to the problem is a good thing, so long as it explains why the restriction results in bad code.

Comment: The explicit constraints of the question might be misguided.

Comment: I don't understand how you can read an answer that complies with the constraints of the question (i.e. provides as the primary suggestion to resize the new images, which in fact will not require retraining the whole model), and yet claim that the answer ***"completely ignore[s] the explicit constraints of the question"***. You could argue that the answer has gone beyond the constraints, but **completely ignored**? If they'd ignored the constraints they wouldn't have provided an answer that complies with the constraints.

Comment: It's a shame the example question and answer are so...trivial. Q: "My new images are the wrong size and I don't want to reprocess my existing data." A: "Resize the new images. Or reprocess your existing data." I mean...what kind of answer were they looking for, really?

Comment: There's no general answer. It depends on how reasonable the constraints are and the risks associated with alternatives. An author's constraints are also often *too restrictive* for what they're actually trying to achieve, and there may be alternatives that meet a lesser constraint. Only an expert in the subject matter can judge those concerns.

Comment: @SteveBennett Actually the fact that they're so trivial makes this a great example for a meta question.

Comment: The second part is useful, too. *Someone else* reading might not realize they can retrain the network on the whole dataset with the new image size.

Comment: Answers that ignore constraints annoy  me, but this one is fine. It provided an answer. If we rearrange the answer so that it said "if you don't want to retrain from scratch with the new image sizes, the you can just resize your images" would you have a problem with that answer?

Comment: FWIW, intuitively I think there might be some trick out there to actually achieve this by applying some operation to the neural network model but I'm not 100% sure. I've never tried this and there's not much on Google. I'm not sure how useful that would be since the model would be quite low resolution and it might be faster to just manually resize images that small (even if there's thousands of them). It seems strange to me that the OP would train on a different resolution image than they would be running with.

Comment: Also IMO the answer is NAA, unambiguously, though consensus seems to be something else. I think a "wrong answer" for "how do I print out 1 2 3 4" is something that tries to print out that string but crashes or has UB or something. I really don't think it's in any way helpful to anyone to keep answers like "get out a sheet of paper and write 1 2 3 4" or "don't print 1 2 3 4, change your major to political science" unless what the OP is asking for is completely impossible like "how do I copy/paste Java code into Python code".

Comment: @jrh the difference between _"no attempt whatsoever at answering any question whatsoever"_ and _"an incorrect, incomplete or irrelevant answer"_ has been chewed out ad nauseum, try searching. It is an answer as far as all rules and guidelines are concerned, and should not be flagged as Not An Answer. If you also think this answer does not attempt to answer the question at all, whether it is correct or not, I'd suggest you read the apples/oranges post again.

Comment: @CodeCaster yep, I know. I've read all the posts and I've been following this sort of thing for years. I'm saying I disagree with the consensus as I mentioned. IMO "an answer" must actually read the OP's question, and e.g., a Java answer on a C++ question should be deleted in most cases. Unless (in an IMO highly unlikely scenario), the Java answer is relevant despite the giant differences in languages (e.g., as pseudocode for a complicated algorithm), but I'm really reaching there.

Comment: I'm also tired of seeing stuff like VSCode answers on Visual Studio questions and vice versa, these things look almost right but are totally useless and just waste time and provide noise, which I think SO should avoid.

Comment: @CodeCaster right, and that's where we disagree. I don't think downvotes are enough. Mods have a lot going on, but I think there should be another path to deletion for cleaning up the site. Semantically I stand by my statement that it's "Not an answer", though I agree that a mod can't handle the flag, I'm saying totally useless, zero effort, "didn't even read the question" answers should be deleted.

Comment: @CodeCaster "delete votes": I don't have those, and probably never will because I can use Google and work in relatively obscure tech (I'd feed the roomba and collect tumbleweed badges if they still existed, not rep, if I posted more), but there's a ton of stuff I run into that is very worthy of the recycle bin, but I can't post it in SO CVR because that'd be a "vote mob", VLQ is a flawed system (I can't even say why it's VLQ, I just have to hope the reviewer sees it), it'd be nice to be able to have a better option for cleaning up the site, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @CodeCaster: _"users should downvote and delete-vote unhelpful answers"_ -- I don't disagree, but I have been taken to task by the SO moderators/community-managers for casting delete votes on genuine attempts to answer. According to them, a delete vote is _only_ for a post that a moderator would delete, i.e. a blatantly off-topic post, a NAA post, or an unsalvageable post. Apparently, an answer that is of very poor quality should not be deleted by anyone other than the author of the answer. :(

Comment: @TaW if the question is misguided I'd try to explain that in a comment, not create an equally misguided answer.

Comment: Well that is you. I would explain it in my answer and show the way to the real issues and solutions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you raise a flag on this I am pretty sure it would be declined with a message

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
> inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This does not warrant a moderator intervention and community members should be able to handle this using upvote/downvote and delete-vote/undelete-vote.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that downvoting costs rep, so most people don't downvote and bad answers stay.

Comment: @Agent_L That's to prevent people from downvoting answers that aren't bad. I try to see it as an investment (but I can miss some reputation). From my experience, in many cases these answers get deleted over time (could take a few months), either by the author removing them, or due to community delete votes. When that happens, you get your reputation back. Another possibility is that the author decides to improve their answer. In that case, you can retract your downvote. Sadly, we aren't notified when that happens, so it's more difficult to follow up on that.

Comment: @g00glen00b If that's the case, why upvoting bad answers is for free? The system is rigged to promote bad answers, eg. I have an answer that is underwater, but the few upvotes still give me more rep than the majority of downvotes takes away. I am encouraged to keep it. I also see lots of useless answers sitting there for years with 0 rep. Unless the answer touches some sensitive subject, people rarely dare to vote down, that's my experience. SE simply doesn't take downvoting seriously and discourages it altogether.

Answer (score 27):

Why do you think this is not an answer?

Remember we're not answering just for the OP, but for later visitors as well.

The OP is asking how to modify training data, and the answer gives a viable workaround: resize the images, and if you don't want that, you need to retrain anyway. The OP may not want that workaround, but later visitors may.

That is an on-topic question and a valid answer. No action needed here from moderators or mob voters at all.

Comment: But the question title contains "without retraining it from scratch", so later visitors will expect to find answer to exactly this question, not to something else...

Comment: @sanyash it will also be shown to people who _don't_ use that phrase. And again, the answers states _"you could do this, or otherwise that"_, so it gives later visitors an idea of the options. So it is an answer in any sense.

Comment: Further to the accurate observation in this Meta answer, I don't even see how one can claim that the answer _"completely ignores"_ the constraint. The answer provides as its first suggestion a solution that obeys the stated constraint. The whole Meta question here seems based on a false premise.

Comment: @CodeCaster With that logic, answers that tell how to `print("Hello World")` to a question that asks about jQuery shouldn't be deleted in case later visitors want that answer.

Comment: @10Rep It's more like telling someone how to do something with jQuery and then pointing out it can also be done with CSS. [Similar to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813071/what-is-the-best-way-to-scroll-to-something-smoothly-with-javascript).

Comment: @sanyash Are *"Resize the new input images to the previous size."* and *"You can either resize the new input images to the previous size or redesign the model with the larger input shape and retrain the model with the new data."* so different that visitors will be confused by the latter and not the former?

Comment: I'd be careful with suggestions to ignore OP restraints. If answer ignores them - downvote and write comment explaining why you think this answer is wrong. And don't worry much: it *may* happens that such answer is useful and it gets its upvotes.

Comment: @Sinatr nobody is suggesting to ignore constraints, and nobody did ignore them.

Comment: @CodeCaster, it's my interpretation of sentence *"The OP may not want that workaround, but later visitors may"* and other comments where you mentioned user searches. Excuse me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sinatr 1) an answer ignoring a constraint is still an answer, and that's what we're talking about here. 2) an answer stating a constraint can't be met, and offering alternatives, is a good answer. 3) unless later searchers explicitly exclude the mentioned constrains, they still get to see the answer that mentions a workaround. So no, I'm not stating that answerers should ignore constraints, but that _if_ they do, they're still valid answers. Whether they are _good_ depends on context and content.

Comment: I don't think resizing the input images should be seen as a workaround. It's a valid solution to this problem within the constrains of the question. It's probably the best solution as well - especially since we know little to nothing about the model OP is using.

Comment: Imho, answers can ignore some specific constraint, *if they can justify explicitly why they are ignoring it*. This applies to many frame-challenge answers ("You are asking X, but your actual problem is Y, and I'm answering that"). If they can't justify, they shouldn't be posted. If the author of the answer believes that other people are interested in the answer without the constraint, they should open a question without that constraint and self-answer.

Comment: +1 - I can't tell you how many questions I've gone to where what I needed was close to but not exactly what the question asked, but one of the answers gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 14):

There's also the issue that sometimes an answer **was** right but the question was updated to exclude it.

Comment: That's not good. If someone asks _"How can I do foo without bar"_, and an answer correctly states _"You can't, you need the bar"_, then that constraint definitely shouldn't be edited out of the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think they're suggesting the other way around: imagine you asked "How can I do foo", someone replied "you need the bar", and then you edited the question to add "without bar"

Comment: In this case though, it seems the question wasn't edited out, so I guess they just decided to ignore the constraint

Comment: @Clockwork Is "You can't, you need the bar" a valid answer to "How can I do foo without bar?"?

Comment: @user253751 From my point of view, if SO was an exam and the question author was the teacher, it wouldn't be, and if SO is a QA website where people can find solutions to similar-ish problems (but not strictly the same), I'd say it depends. I think I would be pretty pissed off if I asked for a Vanilla JS solution and I was told "just do it with X framework" for example.

Comment: @user253751 You know, you made me realise that there might be a boundary issue with how the problem is approached. For example, many people seem to accept that the "without bar" condition can be ignored for anyone stumbling on this problem from a search engine. But is it as accepted to answer a Java question by saying "you can do it like this in Javascript" or would it be blatantly off-topic?

Comment: @Clockwork If the question is "how do I alter the DOM on a web page in Java?" and the answer involves JavaScript... sure!

Comment: I see this all the time. "Please tell me how to do x, but do not say y." I downvote those questions when y is in fact the answer. It's none of the OP's business to tell me how to answer; if the OP knew the way to answer, the OP would not be asking this question in the first place. In that situation, my answer violates the OP's constraints _and is right_. It would be totally wrong to flag it. If I'm mistaken, downvote it (but I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @matt What if 'y' is jQuery? :^)

Comment: @Clockwork Then I wouldn't have read the question to begin with. :)

Answer (score 14):

Not focusing too closely on the specific example, let's look a little broader.

It's a meme here that people will write "[you should use jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)" answers so I hope that points out the broader problem with many of the answers here saying it's OK to ignore constraints. Many things we do set constraints and those can be anything from the language being used to specifications like in this example.

Answers that ignore these limitations are at risk of failing to answer the question. If someone asks how to do something in Python and they get an answer for Perl - I think y'all would all agree that's not an answer. Sure, someone may happen on the question and be looking for an answer about Perl - but that's kinda a silly expectation.

Instead, we have a question about the issue in Perl and a question about Python and visitors get targeted and helpful answers in their language without having to dig through answers to the same question in dozens of other languages on the same post.

So, I would caution y'all from saying "it's fine to ignore restraints, the answer is still correct"... because the important thing is that answers *answer the question that's asked*. If we want the same question without constraints, we can do that but we shouldn't be shoehorning in an answer that ignores constraints.

### Exception(s)

So, there's a couple exceptions to this that I feel are worth bringing up and there are likely others but the key in both is that the answer needs to recognize the question and the constraints and explain why it's necessary to do it another way.

#### It's just not possible.

The first is in situations where what the asker wants just isn't possible.

> You want to do this without _____ but, given the information you've provided, that doesn't seem possible because ______. Instead, you'll need to do ______ and that will solve your problem so that you can get going again.

Sure, proving a negative isn't always possible but it's a good place to start. You can always hedge by saying "as far as I'm aware, what you're asking isn't possible".

#### It's not safe/secure.

Doing something the way the asker wishes is possible but would be a bad practice - it's a security risk, it's leaky, or there's just something about constraints that would cause stuff to break... whatever. The point is, if the asker used the solution they want, it's possible but a terrible choice.

In this situation, you can choose to answer the question or not but the focus should be explaining on why the asker (and future readers) should avoid the solution required by the constraints. Then, provide the standard, safe, recommended solution.

Again, as with the former, it's best to make sure to recognize the constraints from the question so that it's clear to others that you're not just ignoring them and you're providing the best solution you can.

---

In both of these cases, you're doing a lot to really help people understand and grow as programmers - you're not just rotely answering a question, you're helping others to understand *why* a solution is good or necessary. The "Why" is so important! It can help people retain the solution and better understand the language they're using and avoid similar issues in the future.

For cases where an answer fails to do one of the above... that's kinda a hard call. Here on SO y'all have a different definition of what makes an answer than many sites on the network for a variety of historical reasons. When I use or handle NAA flags, I am specifically asking "*Does this answer the question as asked?*" but I'm aware the default on SO is often more along the lines of "Does this answer *a* question?" This disagreement can be seen in the two opposing answers on the [MSE FAQ about NAA flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag).

According to the top answer, I shouldn't use an NAA flag but this answer ignores many other possible issues with answers that the second answer attempts to address, including answers that are answering another question altogether:

> - answers that attempt to **answer another question** or are just a general **dump of unsolicited information**, for example:
>
> > Question: What is the capital of Brazil?
> >
> > Not an answer 1: The capital of Argentina is Buenos Aires.
> >
> > Not an answer 2: Brazil is a state in South America.
> >
> > Not an answer 3: We went to Brazil for our honeymoon.

Now, these examples are pretty blatant but I feel like answers that ignore the constraints of the question fall into the same category. Something more like:

> Question: What color, other than blue is mixed to make green.
>
> Not an answer: Blue is one of the colors mixed to make green.

So, I've not learned anything new in this answer - I already knew blue was one of the colors! I need an answer that tells me "yellow". So, would you delete this answer that says "Blue"? I'd probably call it NAA and leave a comment pointing out the issue to the user, yeah. I know comments can be somewhat stressful but they're really useful for reviewers and mods to see why something may have been flagged as NAA.

> The question already seems aware of blue as an answer to this but is looking for something different. Can you elaborate on why blue is the correct answer or adjust your answer to include the information the question is asking for?

And someone did leave such a comment on the answer outlined in the question here, which is great.

---

Anyway, my recommendation for SO would be to leave a comment like the one immediately above pointing out that the answer might have missed part of the question and encouraging the answer to recognize the limitations of the question and explain why their solution is necessary rather than a solution that would work within the limitations. It's completely possible that the answer is merely incomplete and just needs some additional detail but a comment is the best way to achieve that.

How you want to decide on the flagging issue... I'd recommend that y'all rethink how you view NAAs and why the definition is so narrow here and whether not flagging something that fails to take the entire question into account is the best course of action.

Comment: "I'd recommend that y'all rethink how you view NAAs and why the definition is so narrow here and whether not flagging something that fails to take the entire question into account is the best course of action." That would take SO to be like every other SE site.

Comment: @Braiam You can always try to flag [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936038/getting-project-nuget-configuration-is-invalid-error/40366369#40366369).

Comment: @Scratte as always, the problem is in the question: is it an issue that system administrators should deal with. Programmers write code, sysadmins install stuff.

Comment: @Braiam So you're saying that if an Answer fails to address the Question, the problem is always with the Question? :D

Comment: No @Scratte, I'm saying that the question shouldn't have been asked on SO in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a case for flagging if it does not care for the specific constraints. That's only a case for the downvote button (if you want to apply it).

It brings relevant information to solve the problem (at least under some circumstances) and is with that an answer to the question, even if it is bad.

Given the analogy, it's not a complete orange. It's more like an "*orapple*". Following the discussions linked by you and the SO guidelines "*orapples*" are on-topic and solid answers.

Summary:
The downvote is the tool of choice in this case, not a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem at all with this answer, except that it is a bit short and not worded very well. It does answer the question *including* the constraint - you must resize the images - and then explains that if you don't do that then you would have to violate the constraint. So this doesn't just answer the question, it asserts itself as the *only* answer to the question, because the only alternative would violate the constraint.

I cannot say for sure whether the answer is *correct* about the latter point - it seems plausible that there could be some way to expand a model designed for 128x128 images into a model that works on 256x256 images without starting again from scratch (e.g. introduce a bunch of new nodes with duplicated weights, or weights set at zero) - but by my reading, the answer certainly does not ignore the constraint.