# User keeps posting blatantly off-topic answers - what to do?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, specific-user

While looking through NAABot for problematic answers that could be improved/flagged, I noticed one that was blatantly off-topic ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74368445/74368507#74368507) to deleted post). Flagged it as Not an Answer and continued on. Later, though, I noticed that the [same user](https://stackoverflow.com/u/20387401) (now deleted), who had written the previous answer, posted more answers of the same style, which were also completely off-topic. Looking at their answer history, I can clearly see that every single one of them is about the same thing - that to fix your code problems, *buy a suitcase*, like Charles Simonyi. I don't know, it's just completely random and unnecessary.

What are the steps I should take here? NAA flag on every answer, hoping for an answer ban? Custom flag to bring it to moderator attention? Just downvote?

Comment: Several downvotes on answers should quickly add up to answer ban.

Comment: That type of repeating non-answer looks to be an abuse of the site. I myself have flagged them rude/abusive. NAA isn't strong enough to quickly squash this abusive behavior.

Comment: They've been properly answer banned, but yeah, R/A flags apply to this particular user

Comment: It looks like a spam bot of some sort. Post random content as answers for some random questions and hope for the occasional upvote? In order to get a foothold for the real spam? The minimum post length is circumvented by using a link. (Downvotes are much less likely as they cost one reputation point)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I agree but then we need to call it an abuse bot, because in the SO definition of spam, it isn't spam.

Comment: Wait you're telling me that won't solve my code problems? I spent $300 on this suit case what the heck!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

These sorts of posts are not *simply* off-topic. It's not uncommon for those less experienced with Stack Overflow to make off-topic posts that don't meet the minimum thresholds for being a question or answer, despite being made in good faith.

Posts like the one you're referring to

```
[Image of Charles Simonyi in suitcase][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/<omitted>.jpg
```

are not in the above category. Rather, they are **abuse** and should be flagged as such. There is no conceivable way that someone making such a post would think that it would be acceptable here. It has nothing to do with anything, and [can be red flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035) just like cat-on-keyboard nonsense can be red flagged. New users who accumulate such flags run into account restrictions much more rapidly than those who may have some posts removed due to being NAA, so if you want to stem the tide of nonsense ASAP, rude/abusive flags are the way to go.

In the unlikely event that you happen to find someone who's somehow able to continue to make such posts, in addition to flagging them as R/A, if you wanted, you could raise a custom moderator flag asking for the user to be looked into. (But keep in mind that custom flags can take a while to be handled, while R/A flags are often handled within the hour)

Answer (score 9):

Answers that are completely wrong or won't help at all [are not low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality). Similarly, answers that merely [misunderstand the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality) or even [ignore the question's explicit constraints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401134/are-answers-that-completely-ignore-the-explicit-constraints-of-the-question-very) aren't low-quality.

However, the link you posted isn't just irrelevant, it's trolling. There's no way that a legitimate user could've seen that as a serious contribution. That being said, it should be flagged as Rude/Abusive.